# Avoiding duplicate Autobahn connections

Tags: autobahn, autobahnws

How is it possible to ensure that Autobahn only creates **a single** connection?

Is it possible to either check for existing connections before calling `connection.open`, or perhaps kill all other connections on `connection.onopen`?

Answer (score -1):

When using AutobahnJS (which I assume this relates to), you will generally not need to open multiple connections. If your application connects to a single WAMP server, then you can use the single connection for all WAMP actions while it persists, i.e. for all your subscriptions, publishes, registrations and calls.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question - whether or not it's necessary, how can multiple connections be found?

Comment: There is no way to check for existing connections with the library, as the library only serves as a constructor for the connection objects. You will need to implement your own tracking for this.